# Transgression against someone's right

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, forgiveness, human-rights

Assalamu Alaikum.
I am really scared about this. The thing is that
Me and someone else (a fellow) transgressed against someone's right. He gave me an idea and i just remained silent and he did the transgression (so i am also involved in this). Now after being guided  it has come to my mind that i should apologize to the person whose right we transgressed against and also restore his right in some way if possible but by telling him that we did such a thing would expose the fellow with whom i trangressed .
**So should I hide his sin or apologize to the person by exposing him?**

Answer (score 0):

You should make things right, hiding sins in islam is not about not admiting your sin, it is the oposite, you should know your sin and admit it bit you should not go around telling people about your sin with out need.

You should go to the person and speak to him/her and tell her what you did, ask for forgivness from the person and look if there is anything that could be done to fix the misstake